# Xcode4, iOS: Certain parts of instance method being ignored, no errors, just passed by

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

new iOS guy here. I have a problem that Googling and searching on here has not shed any light on. I'm assuming this is basic. I have a simple app (app delegate and 1 view controller), and as part of it I'm using local notification. So, in the app delegate I use the 'didReceiveLocalNotification' to watch for the notifications. Depending on which one comes in, I then call one of several instance methods in my main view controller.

ie in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification: (UILocalNotification *)notification {
   MyViewController* controller = [[MyViewController alloc] autorelease];
   if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"myKey"]) {
     [controller checkActive];
   }
 }
```

Through logging and watching some breakpoints, this is all working. If the app is in the background, the notification comes in, app opens, and the correct instance method is called.

What I cannot figure out at all is why some parts of the instance method are simply being passed by, with no effect. For a simple example, if we have this:

```
-(void)checkActive {
    ViewThing.alpha = 1.0;
    NSLog(@"checkActive ran");
}
```

The log statement will show up fine, but the ViewThing will not change. Elsewhere in the main view controller I'm calling the same checkActive method with no problems and it changes the ViewThing. (via another interface button IBAction method in that case).

There are no errors, no warnings, the console shows nothing, putting a breakpoint on ViewThing shows that it hits the line. I'm stumped, cannot see what is different from trying to calling the method from the delegate vs. on an IBAction.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

If the `alpha` is not correctly changing there a few possible issues with 1 and 2 being the most likely.

1. `ViewThing` is `nil`. Reasons could be is the view unloaded and you set it to nil or checkActive was called before the outlets were set.
2. `ViewThing.alpha` is being set on a thread that is not the main thread. Attempting to change UI elements on a separate thread will caused undefined behavior such as never updating the change or taking an extended amount of time to update the change. You can check if it is the main thread using `[NSThread isMainThread]`.
3. `ViewThing` is pointing a different view.

1 & 2 can easily be checked by logging view

```
NSLog(@"checkActive ran %@", ViewThing);
```

Comment: That was helpful Joe. I did your NSLog as suggested and it prints out "checkActive ran (null) and I also put a breakpoint on it and doing a 'po ViewThing' says that it Can't print the description of a NIL object. So I guess it is un loading issue. Not sure how to handle that, since it doesn't seem good to leave every single element I might need to adjust loaded all the time...

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use instance variables to maintain state while the view is not loaded. This way when the viewDidLoad is called you can set up your state again. In your case when checkActive is called you can set an iVar of type BOOL to YES and when your view loads you can set the alpha appropriately.

Comment: Thanks much Joe. Can you take one more moment of pity on a noob and give me a tiny sliver of code to get me pointed in the right direction? I did a lot of searching around and there are just so many different places in the code to "do stuff" that I've not been able to determine where to start. Conceptually I know what is going on I just can't find the road to get me there. Thanks again, folks like me really to appreciate the expertise.

Comment: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ Scroll down to step 5 "Designing a Class interface" instance variables go in the header file so just create a `BOOL activeChecked;` and set that to yes when checkActive is called. Inside of your viewDidLoad simply type `if(activeChecked) ViewThing.alpha = 1.0;`

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and direction. It's always hard when you are an expert in other things and get tossed into a whole new arena. You feel so helpless not knowing anything. :)